# Send message to specific consumer in celery (via routing key)

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

Does `Celery` support to specifically send a message to a specific consumer/client, e.g. via a routing key?

By default `RabbitMQ` a machine can targeted by using a direct queue, but I am trying to achieve the same behaviour with Celery

```
@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


# something like this
add.delay(1, 2, "machine-xyz")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run your `worker-xyz` as `-Q worker-abc-queue` to make it listen to a specific queue and then specify this queue name when you are calling the task to route it

```
add.apply_async((1, 2), {}, queue='worker-abc-queue')
```

Comment: Yes, this is the typical solution to the problem.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The alternative is to set `queue` argument in Celery `app.task` decorator, which would be convenient if it's not necessary to route every message programmatically in your case.

```py
@app.task(queue='YOUR_QUEUE_NAME')
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

# so you don't need to specify queue or routing key every time when your code invokes it.
add.delay(1, 2)
```